# Outputting a line of 90 equals signs to the console, with blank lines either side

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I am trying to write a method that outputs a blank line, then 90 = signs on a new line, and finally a blank line at the end.

This is my code...

```
public void easyToRead(){
    for (int i=0; i<=EQUAL_SIGNS; i++){
        if (i >= 0){
            if (i == EQUAL_SIGNS || i == 0){
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("=");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output should look like this...

```
blah blah blah

======================= ---> 90 of them

blah blah blah
```

Could someone please help me to correct my code.

Comment: Can u explain your question?
What is the use of if(i>=0) in line 4. It is going to be true always, as long as the loop is running.No else case is written too.

Comment: You don't need your first if-statement. You initiate i as 0, then only increment it. Also, finding good tutorials on logical OR and AND should take you 1 sec of googling. For looping, read some "java for beginners"-book

Comment: Why don't you create the string in memory first, and then use System.out.println to dump the whole thing to screen?

Comment: Can you just give us the text output that you want? I'm having trouble following what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're on the right track with the `for` loop, but you shouldn't really need any `if` statements. Something like this might be simpler...

```
public void easyToRead() {
    // Write a blank line
    System.out.println();

    // Write the 90 equals characters
    for (int i=0; i<90; i++){
        System.out.print("=");
    }

    // Write a new-line character to end the 'equals' line
    System.out.println();

    // Write a blank line
    System.out.println();
}
```

Which would output...

```
<blank line>
===========================...
<blank line>
// the next output will write on this line
```

For each blank line you want, just add another `System.out.println();` statement

Comment: Use `System.out.println()` to print a new line since it could be something else then `\n`.

Comment: ...and I think he wants a new line before printing the '='s... :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've been editing my post with your suggestions, and modified to suit the new requirements from the user :-)

Comment: perfect, thankyou! I realised I probably shouldnt have been trying to place it all in the for loop :) silly me :P

Comment: No problems. Please make sure you 'tick' one of the answers, so everyone knows that your question has been solved.

Comment: +1 for your answer and for your remark on my answer which helps me becoming a better developer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%n%90s%n"," ").replaceAll(" ", "="));
```

Comment: Yes, except with a line space either side of the equal signs.

Comment: You mean a line feed, right? Added! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine you want to use as many equal signs as you want.

In your class, create a static block

```
public static String LINE_EQUAL_SIGNS;

public static String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator").toString();

static {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    for (int i = 0; i < EQUAL_SIGNS; i++)
        sb.add("=");
    sb.add(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    LINE_EQUAL_SIGNS = sb.toString();
}
```

Now you only need to do :

```
public void easyToRead()
{
    System.out.print(LINE_EQUAL_SIGNS);
}
```

Comment: You should use the `lineSeparator` property instead of `\n`. (I didn't downvote however..)

Comment: +1 then :) best solution if used alot! (you could use `String.format..` :))

Comment: @downvoter can I know why you downvoted me ?

Comment: @dacwe : thanks for the remark and the +1 :)

Comment: I didn't get the upvote.. I think, hahah! :) (It's all right anyways! :) :), it's not a bad answer @WATTO Studios provided... )

Comment: Yeah I think he meant you @dacwe